# Простейшая php форма не работает

Tags: php

Делаю простейшую форму на php, но данные не отправляются, хотя все указывает о успешном выполнении `submit`. Пытался сделать другие формы, бывало приходит сообщение, но данных как будто нет,они не записаны в переменную. В общем не работает данная форма, не говоря уже о пустых строках. Помогите!

```js
    <?php
 $toWho = "worddoc96hiphop@gmail.com";
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $second = $_POST['second'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $mess = "Имя: " . $name . " \nОтчество: " . $second . " \nEmail: " . $email . " \nСообщение: " . $message;
 if(mail($toWho, "Новое письмо", $mess)) {
 echo 'Success';
 } else echo 'DAMN';
 ?>
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="form" action='php/main.php' name="form">
      <div class="input-1">
        <label for="">Имя:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Иван" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" name="name" id="name">
      </div>
      <div class="input-1">
        <label for="">Отчество:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Иванович" required="required" name="second" id="second">
      </div>
      <div class="email">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
      </div>
      <input type="email" placeholder="example@mail.ru" required="required" name="email" id="email">
      <div class="message">
        <label for="area">Сообщение:</label>
      </div>
      <textarea cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Введите сообщение..." required="required" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
      <div class="sbm">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Цитата: "данные не отправляются, хотя все указывает о успешном выполнении". Какую-нибудь ошибку выводит при отправке?

Comment: Нет, наоборот выводит echo Success. Скрипт выглядит верным?

Comment: В PHP есть такая опция как отображение ошибок. По умолчанию она отключена. То, что выводит "Success", ещё само по себе ни о чём не говорит. К слову, все данные из полей формы приходят на сервер. Что приходит в виде email (если вообще приходит)?

Comment: Ничего не приходит. До этого пробовал по другому сделать скрипт, приходили пустые поля и всё

Answer (score 2):

Причины, почему ты не можешь отправить почту:

1)На локальном сервере не настроен sendmail, либо smtp

2)На удаленном сервере запрещена функция `mail()`

Если же ты пользуешься локальным сервером, то у тебя должен создаться txt-файл, куда будут заноситься твои письма, если после строки    `$message = $_POST['message'];` добавишь код ниже, в итоге ты поймешь, что данная форма работает, только данные не отправляются на email из-за причин выше:

//Сохраняем в базу данных

```
$f = fopen("message.txt", "a+");

fwrite($f," \n Сообщение от $toWho. Кому: $email. Имя: $name. Отчество: $second");

fwrite($f,"\n $message ");

fwrite($f,"\n ---------------");

fclose($f);
```